# Apex - Display Text on Page

Tags: text, oracle-apex, apex

I need to add some Pages to our Oracle Apex Application, which have to work as sort of an Instruction for new people in the Team. When I add a `Static Content`, to the page, I can add some text to it. But when I start a new line in the Source Box, this new line does not show up in Apex.

Do I need to use something different for text, or?

Kind Regards
Elias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help section in the page builder shows that this region expects html. It's perfectly possible to put in plain text without any html but as you state, newlines aren't guaranteed.
Basic example of text with a line break as region source for static content region:

```
<p>
Hello<br>
World
</p>
```

Depending on the requirement, it's possible to use any html element, css (inline or defined in page header), javascript etc